# Determinant of Partitioned Upper Triangular Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

> Let $F$ is some field. Suppose that $M \in M_{n \times n}(F)$ can be written as $$M = \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ 0 & I \\ \end{bmatrix},$$ where $A$ is a square matrix. Prove that $\det(M) = \det(A)$.

Is there a way to fix the following proof? First note that it is easy to prove that $\det( \begin{bmatrix} P & 0 \\ 0 & I \\ \end{bmatrix}) = \det(P)$. Let $P$ and $Q$ be those invertible matrices such that $PAQ = D$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix having amount of $1$'s along its diagonal equal to rank of $A$. Then

$$ \det(M) = \det(\begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ 0 & I \\ \end{bmatrix})$$

$$= \det(\begin{bmatrix} P^{-1}DQ^{-1} & B \\ 0 & I \\ \end{bmatrix})$$

$$=\det(\begin{bmatrix} P^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & I \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} D & PB \\ 0 & I \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} Q^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & I \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

$$=\det(P^{-1}) \det(\begin{bmatrix} D & PB \\ 0 & I \\ \end{bmatrix}) \det(Q^{-1})$$

Since the middle determinant is clearly the determinant of an upper triangular matrix, it will be product of $D$'s diagonal elements and $I$'s elements; i.e., $\det(P^{-1}) \det(D) \det(Q^{-1}) = \det(P^{-1}DQ^{-1}) = \det(A)$, which proves the theorem.

Okay. I realize I am being rather fast and loose with the dimension of the matrices. I am trying to avoid as much induction as possible; so far as I can tell, the only thing that needs to be proven through induction is $\det( \begin{bmatrix} P & 0 \\ 0 & I \\ \end{bmatrix}) = \det(P)$ My only problem is that $PB$ may not be defined, but I am hoping that this doesn't prove t be an insuperable problem for my proof.

Comment: An easier approach is to do the [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) on the bottom row of the original matrix. This yields the result without appealing to the SVD decomposition. Regarding your question about whether $PB$ exists or not, I think the dimension-matching is fine because $A$ is a square matrix.

Comment: To find the determinant of $A$, we could reduce it to its row echelon form $R$. Since R is a triangular matrix, its determinant is simply the product of the entries in the main diagonal. Then det A = k(det R) for some suitable for $k$. The row echelon form of M is the same as M with A replaced by R and B replaced by some other matrix. Then M is a triangular matrix and the product of the entries in the main diagonal remain the same since the entries in the diagonal of the identity matrix are all 1s.

Comment: Since adding a multiple of one row to another doesn't change the value of the determinant we can use the bottom half of the matrix to reduce $B$ to the zero matrix without altering the determinant. As you noted it's easy to prove from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier approach is to do the [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) on the bottom row of the original matrix. This yields the result without appealing to the SVD decomposition. Regarding your question about whether $PB$ exists or not, I think the dimension-matching is fine because $A$ is a square matrix.